# Rails 4 - Geocoder hitting query limit in test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

When running my test suite, about half the time it will go red because I am hitting the geocoding per second query limit:

```
Google Geocoding API error: over query limit.
```

I am using the geocoder gem with google maps / places api.

It seems like I need to set some sort of sleep option, but in the geocoder documentation, the only mention of this is for a rake task. How can I set it up, or prevent my test suite from making too many geocode requests per second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not specific to the geocoder gem, your best bet is probably stubbing out the service somehow.

You have a few options:

1. You could turn on caching in your test environment so you only make one external http request per day. [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) has some good examples of  [ActiveSupport::Cache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache.html). The relevant section is [low-level caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching). While this may work for you, I think its a bit overly-complicated for your situation.
2. **I recommend mocking out the external HTTP service all together.** [Thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests) has a somewhat outdated but still relevant guide to setting up [Webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock), a popular library for mocking out external HTTP services. It integrates well with all of the popular testing frameworks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach for testing with the Geocoder gem is described in the [README](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#testing-apps-that-use-geocoder)

Add this to your `spec/support` (or equivalent) directory and the error messages should stop.

```
# spec/support/geocoder.rb
Geocoder.configure(:lookup => :test)
Geocoder::Lookup::Test.set_default_stub(
  [
    {
      'latitude'     => 40.7143528,
      'longitude'    => -74.0059731,
      'address'      => 'New York, NY, USA',
      'state'        => 'New York',
      'state_code'   => 'NY',
      'country'      => 'United States',
      'country_code' => 'US'
    }
  ]
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }
```

[Avoiding Unnecessary API Requests](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)